Change driver in yocto build imx93
I am a complete newbie to the Yocto world,
i am trying to change a driver in yocto.
To build yocto i follow the guide from:
https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Build_Release&release=mx93-yocto-mickledore-6.1.36_2.1.0-v2.3 but with langdale -m imx-6.1.1-1.0.1.xml instead of mickledore -m imx-6.1.36-2.1.0.xml.
$ mkdir -p ~/bin
$ curl https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
$ export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
$ mkdir ~/var-fsl-yocto
$ cd ~/var-fsl-yocto
$ repo init -u https://github.com/varigit/variscite-bsp-platform.git -b langdale -m imx-6.1.1-1.0.1.xml
$ repo sync -j$(nproc)
$ cd ~/var-fsl-yocto
$ MACHINE=imx93-var-som DISTRO=fsl-imx-xwayland . var-setup-release.sh build_xwayland
$ cd ~/var-fsl-yocto
$ source setup-environment build_xwayland
$ bitbake fsl-image-gui

with this i getting a working yocto image, now i want to add the driver for RC1337.
I add a new layer var-fsl-yocto/sources/meta-test
with following files:
layer.conf:
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "meta-test"
BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-test = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-test = "6"

LAYERDEPENDS_meta-test = "core"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-test = "kirkstone langdale"

ds1337.patch:
--- a/arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/imx93.dtsi
+++ b/arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/imx93.dtsi

@@ -293,17 +293,12 @@
                clock-names = "pclk", "fast_clk", "slow_clk";
                status = "disabled";
            };
-
-           lpi2c1: i2c@44340000 {
-               compatible = "fsl,imx93-lpi2c", "fsl,imx7ulp-lpi2c";
-               reg = <0x44340000 0x10000>;
-               interrupts = <GIC_SPI 13 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
-               clocks = <&clk IMX93_CLK_LPI2C1_GATE>,
-                    <&clk IMX93_CLK_BUS_AON>;
-               clock-names = "per", "ipg";
-               dmas = <&edma1 7 0 0>, <&edma1 8 0 1>;
-               dma-names = "tx","rx";
-               status = "disabled";
+           
+           &i2c1 {
+               rtc: ds1337@68 {
+               compatible = "dallas,ds1337";
+               reg = <0x68>;
+               };
            };
 
            lpi2c2: i2c@44350000 {

rtc.cfg:
CONFIG_RTC_DRV_DS1337=y

linux-variscite_%.bbappend:
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI += "file://rtc.cfg \
            file://ds1337.patch"

after this i use the following commands:
$ bitbake fsl-image-gui -c cleansstate
$ bitbake fsl-image-gui -c patch

i dont get an Error massage but the file imx93.dtsi dont change.
Like a said i am very new to yocto, so maybe i am an the wrong path?

you should run "bitbake linux-variscite" to build just the patched kernel and dtb first. You can also do a devshell and ensure the patch changes takes place.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
